useState and custom hooks pattern
Coming from Angular I am having difficulty structuring a simple demo with React as I run into infinite loops and other side effects.
I have a GamePage.tsx (container component) that the user navigates from the home page. When this component loads, I fetch some data from an API with Tanstack Query (code wrapped in a custom hook).
According to the result, I store the result in the component's state prop and display a child component with it.
However, while I think storing the returned data from the API seems a good candidate to be held in the components' state, by setting it would trigger an infinite loop.
Should I have to create another child component in the GamePage.tsx just to use/call the custom hook? This seems a bit too verbose and not really bringing benefits as the container component is already pretty minimal.
Considering the case below (Container component -> Fetch Data -> init child component) what should be changed in my solution to follow the "React way"? From the docs I could not find a unique/common answer for this.
The custom Hook
const useWordByDifficulty = ({ difficulty }: { difficulty: Difficulty }) => {    
    const wishedLength = mapDifficultyToLength(difficulty);

    return useQuery({
        queryKey: [],
        queryFn: () => httpFetch(`API_URL`)
    });
};

GamePage.tsx
const GamePage = () => {
    const { state }: { state: { difficulty: Difficulty } } = useLocation();

    // While I think the state here might be a good choice, it triggers an infinite loop setting it in the code below 
    //const [gameWord, setGameWord] = useState<string | null>(null);
    
    let reqStatus: HttpResponseStatus | null = null;
    let gameWord: string | null = null;

    // useEffect(() => { <-- This is not permitted as useWordByDifficulty is a custom hook
        let active = true;        

        // The API is called twice
        const { data, error, isPending, isError } = useWordByDifficulty(state)
        if (active) {
            if (isPending) {
                reqStatus = 'isPending';
            } else if (isError) {
                reqStatus = 'isError';
            } else {
               // If I set the word here, I get an infinite loop as the component re-render
               // setGameWord(data);
                reqStatus = 'isSuccess';
            }
        }

        return () => {
            // cleanup
            active = false;
        }
    // }, [state]);


    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Game Page</h1>
            <h3>Diff: {state.difficulty}</h3>
            {reqStatus === 'isPending' && <div>Loading...</div>}
            {reqStatus === 'isError' && <div>An error occurred...</div>}
            {reqStatus === 'isSuccess' && <GameWord gameWord={gameWord} difficulty={state.difficulty}></GameWord>}
        </div>
    )
};


Keep your custom hooks out of the useEffect and call them from the root of your component. You can then call the resulting data from inside your useEffect and add the data to the dependency array of the useEffect.

In this case then no need to have a state for the data part? Any hint why the API call is triggered twice? Not having any useEffect nor useState I would expect it to  be called only once.

While the question can look/sound trivial to some, I still think it is legit, therefore downvoting it without any feedback seems just a bad, yet common, habit

If your only intention is to write the data to a variable then you indeed can just skip the useEffect and useState. The API is likely triggered twice due to you debugging with <StrictMode> (used to check for missing Effect cleanups), in which case it works as intended. Otherwise it could be caused by a bad implementation of a custom hook (running with re-renders), but since you just return results of a widely used and tested hook that shouldn't be the case.

Thanks @NotFound for the explanation. If you create an answer with your points I would accept it as it confirms my initial thoughts and explains the open parts.

Keep your custom hooks out of the useEffect (see also Rules of Hooks) and call them from the root of your component. You can then call the resulting data from inside your useEffect and add the data to the dependency array of the useEffect. If your only intention is to write the data to a variable then you can skip the useEffect and useState.
The API is likely triggered twice due to you debugging with <StrictMode> (used to check for missing Effect cleanups), in which case it works as intended. Otherwise it could be caused by a bad implementation of a custom hook (running with re-renders), but since you only return results of a widely used and tested hook that shouldn't be the case.
